# Web API and application/x-www-form-urlencoded JSON

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a webhook that receives data from a third party source. Unfortunately, they post data to me in a very strange and improper way. Nonetheless, this is what I have to deal with. They are sending data with a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the following format:

```
randomJsonObjects: 
[
  {
    "email": "john@example.com",
    "timestamp": 1337197600,
    "id": "55555",
  },
  {
    "email": "johnny@example.com",
    "timestamp": 1337547600,
    "id": "44444",
  }
]
```

Of course that is not valid JSON, but it's not being sent as such either. My problem is I can not get Web API to parse this out correctly. Generally with JSON I just use this as my controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Create(List<MyObject> jsonObjects)
```

But that doesn't work. I've tried numerous options and always ends up with null values.

Comment: Actually your data *is* valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

You have to use newtonsoft.json

There are able to unserialize anonymous objects and pretty much every json stuff
go check out : http://json.codeplex.com/

for you case i think a simple line like this will do the trick:

```
List<dynamic> randomJsonObjects= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(randomJsonObjects);
```

the problem si that your code start by randomJsonObjects: so you just have to remove it and after call the line above.
or add the { } to transform it as an object

Comment: I'm not really sure the text is in valid Json format. Trying to paste it in [JSParse](http://json.parser.online.fr/) fails.

Comment: It's not, which is definitely the source of the problem. I can get it to work just fine if it's valid JSON, but unfortunately I have no control over what is posted to me.

Answer (score 0):

The data-structure that is being encoded in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` closely resembles [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx).

Capture the query string and try to parse it using [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx). In addition, [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767549/is-there-a-net-ready-made-method-to-process-response-body-of-a-httplistener-htt) might help

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if the following fits your needs...here I am making a big assumption that the format for the request content would be always like `randomJsonObjects:[.....]` and hence I try to first parse to see if its a valid json and if not I am adding a wrapping `{`, `}` characters.

Of course this can be improved so that you always handle some type of parameters (ex: `AddressBook` in this case) specially and so you might want to write the following logic into something like `HttpParameterBinding` in which case wherever this parameter is used on the action, the following workaround would be used...

```
public async Task Post()
{
    bool validJson = false;
    string originalData = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    try
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Parse(originalData);
        validJson = true;
    }
    catch (JsonReaderException)
    {
    }

    string modifiedData = null;
    if (!validJson)
    {
        modifiedData = "{" + originalData + "}";
    }
    else
    {
        modifiedData = originalData;
    }

    AddressBook book = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddressBook>(modifiedData);

    //TODO: do something with the book
}

public class AddressBook
{
    [JsonProperty("randomJsonObjects")]
    public IEnumerable<ContactInfo> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class ContactInfo
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public long TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```